# Skip the first element in list

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible with django template tags to skip the first element in a list when doing the for loop? For example I want to begin from element 1 instead from 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

builtin [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter

```
{{ qs|slice:"1:" }}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a hero! I was able to make this work for my needs with: {% for article in articles|slice:"1:" %}

Answer (score 5):

You can e.g. do:

```
{% if not forloop.first %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```